# Boost timer limit

Tags: c++, boost, timestamp, timing

I need to measure an elapsed time (or some sort of timestamp - doesn't matter if it's the system time or something that started from 0) in milliseconds, and was interested in using the `boost::cpu_timer` class to do this.

Is it un-wise to use this class for an extended period of time (i.e. a week straight of non-stop measuring)? Is there an alternative solution?

From my experience with getting the system timestamp, I've gradually come to the assumption that obtaining the timestamp in milliseconds (which is what I need) every couple of milliseconds is incredibly slow and strenuous.

Comment: Because your question is incredibly vague.

Comment: How is it vague? I'm asking if cpu_timer is built for long-durations of measurement. How much more specific can I be?

Comment: If something is vague one does not simply down vote questions, but writes a comment and says SPECIFICALLY what's missing...
Also your comment is vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [boost::chrono](http://www.boost.org/libs/chrono/) or [std::chrono](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) better solve this problem

Comment: That's what I was figuring would be the case.